# Load and pass URL into div express.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
    });
});
</script>


<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>
```

1. Above is jquery method , load and pass url into div simply.
2. But I don't want to use this front end method on express.js.
3. I want to use middleware or function or method (NO JQUERY).

How I can load and pass remote or external link into div when button clicked on express.js?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the front-end (view) with the back-end (server), you will still need to execute a network request in your view to fetch the remote data/external link.

Middleware exists on the back-end (server), you can't invoke a function on the back-end from the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

If you use template engine (like EJS) then you can make a template that will fill div with whatever you want.

server:

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";
response.render('index', link);
```

.ejs file:

```
<div> <%= link %> </div>
```

which will render into:

```
<div>http://www.google.com</div>
```

Otherwise you have no other choice if you want to load content from server side with server side functions.